# What's a good word for "Expensive, but worth the money?"

Tags: expressions, adjectives, money

I'm categorizing some products, and am lumping the cheapest ones together under "Budget-friendly." However, I'm having trouble with the high-priced group name.

Basically, I'm looking for a shorter (1-2 words) version of "Expensive, but *so* worth it!"

TIA,

JSB

Comment: Investment quality

Comment: @ab2 Thanks for the idea. Not quite what I had in mind - since I'm looking for "worth it right now," not "possibly worth it in the future."

Comment: ***Extravagant**?*

Comment: professional grade/quality, high end, high performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **premium**
>
> adjective  ​ C2 used to refer to something that is of higher than
>   usual quality [*our premium model*]

[[CED](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/premium)]

(though see the caveat at [Better than premium](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33050/better-than-premium))

Comment: Sadly, a lot of stuff labelled "premium" is so only in price.

Comment: Are you saying that other advertising jargon is for some strange reason more reliable?

Comment: I'm pointing out that truth is not guaranteed to be found in everyday usage

Comment: That was the point of the last part of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

A bit of a range of suggestions - hopefully some of them might be useful:

1. Good value
2. Value for money
3. Superior
4. Premier
5. Deluxe
6. Luxurious
7. Elite

If you're talking about a particular service, rather than an item, then something like *expert*, *consummate*, *professional*, or *accomplished* might be a better fit.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure the word you're looking for is a ***splurge***.

Such as when people go on a shopping spree, they ***splurge*** on expensive items they feel are absolutely worth it to them right that moment.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with **value**

Comment: But it does. You don't splurge on cheap things.

Comment: I respectfully disagree.   I could splurge by buying  100 of some cheap thing even tho I only need 2

Comment: Right, but we're talking about a group of items, some of which are inexpensive (which you could purchase a ton of them and only need one or two and that's a splurge due to the amount of money you're spending on all of them collectively), and some of which are expensive (which are worth it DESPITE their cost or value), and are also a splurge even just getting one.

Comment: "splurge" connotes that it's not actually valuable and quite unnecessary. Collins Learner Dictionary: "If you splurge on something, you spend a lot of money, usually on things that you do not need."

Answer (score -2):

This isn't a perfect match, but "undervalued at that price,"  or just "undervalued,"  suggests you're getting a good deal.

Comment: This has nothing to do with actual cost, only with perceived worth. Undervalued is for something that is not valued enough.

Comment: @psosuna "actual cost"  is exactly why the item is undervalued.   "Value" is determined entirely by what someone else would pay for it.   Check economic theory.

Comment: I think you're thinking too hard. OP has essentially a 2-column list of "expensive" and "inexpensive" items. Some are "budget-friendly", the others are "undervalued"? Here, using undervalued really is talking to the perceived worth of the product.