# "Premium" means just high cost or is it includes high quality?

Tags: meaning

**Country : India**

I have plan to build a web design company. I have to user tag line as something like "Premium Web Design Service" or "Premium Web Design"....

I want to know that "Premium" means just high cost or is it includes high quality too?

Comment: This has certainly been answered at [Better than premium](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33050/better-than-premium), where the polysemy of 'premium' is discussed. There is also comment on whether or not using  'premium', with the 'higher cost' sense available, is wise in marketing. // Dictionary definitions are required, but probably will not help with the judgement call.

Comment: It is meaningless, as an advertising term.

Answer (score 0):

In your context, 'Premium', as a modifier, denotes a commodity of superior quality and therefore also implies a higher price.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/premium

Comment: But [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/premium) ('BrE') has  << 4... an offer of something free or at a specially reduced price as an inducement to buy a commodity or service [/ ...] (as modifier)
_a premium offer_ >>.  But I'd accept that the default sense here is the one you give. The word's a monster.